# React Native JSON API Networking With Express

Tags: json, ajax, express, react-native, network-programming

I am attempting to create a React Native app with an Express server / PostgreSQL database.  I have the following fetch request in one of my components

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
    this.setState({
        users: true
      })
    })
   }
```

The '/users' endpoint is defined in my server file as:

```
app.get('/users', (request, response) => {
   Users.all().then(users => {
   const templateData = {};
   templateData.data = users;
   response.json(templateData);
  })
});
```

The server is listening on port 4567

In package.json, I have a proxy set up like this:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
```

My issue is that I keep getting a 'Network request failed' error when componentDidMount is called.  Any ideas on how to get my server to communicate with my components?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have not used "proxy" before, but your first issue is that your URL path contains the wrong port. If your server is listening on port 4567, your URL path should be "http://localhost:4567".

I would suggest making your fetch request with this full URL, rather than just the /users path. 
Ex/

```
fetch('http://localhost:4567/users')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
this.setState({
users: true
})
```

Comment: Hi Neil, Thanks very much for your response.  I removed the proxy and amended the path to contain the localhost and port but I'm getting the same error unfortunately : [